# Creating relationship type between two nodes neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a relationship between two nodes and for some reason I am unable to do to.

```
MATCH (C:Company {Company: 'Node1'})
MATCH (J:Company {Company: 'Node2'})
MERGE (C)-[:Partner]-(J);
```

I'm getting the result (no changes, no records).  Before trying to create this relationship, I uploaded a csv with the following cypher:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///company_info.csv' AS line
MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
ON CREATE SET
C.Partner = line.Partner,
C.Product = line.Product,
C.Partners = line.Partners,
C.Customers = line.Customers
ON MATCH SET
C.Partner = line.Partner,
C.Product = line.Product,
C.Partners = line.Partners,
C.Customers = line.Customers
```

I know that the C.Partner = line.Partner created a partner property not a relationship type.  Any suggestions on what I can do here to create the relationship type?

Answer (score 1):

So, according to a comment to the other answer, your actual issue is that you created a `Company` node with the wrong property value ("Node1 " instead of "Node1"). Therefore, your first `MATCH` clause failed.

To change the node property value from "Node1 " to "Node1" via Cypher, you can do this:

```
MATCH (c:Company {Company: 'Node1 '})
SET c.Company = 'Node1';
```

If this is a general problem, you can trim whitespace from both ends of that property value in all `Company` nodes this way:

```
MATCH (c:Company)
SET c.Company = TRIM(c.Company);
```

*If you just want to trim on the right side, can can use the `RTRIM` function instead of `TRIM`.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a direction for the relationship.

```
MATCH (C:Company {Company: 'Node1'})
MATCH (J:Company {Company: 'Node2'})
MERGE (C)-[:Partner]->(J);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just tried that and I'm getting (no changes, no records).

Comment: Does `MATCH (C:Company {Company: 'Node1'}) MATCH (J:Company {Company: 'Node2'}) RETURN C, J` return your two nodes?

Comment: I found out what the issue was.  In the csv file the naming of Node1had an extra character in it.  'Node1 '  is there anyway I can modify this through Cypher?